# An external file with macros

Tags: macros, lyx

I have many common macros in all my documents. how can I move them all to external file, and include it in each document?

Comment: put them in `mydefs.sty` and then add `\usepackage{mydefs}` (however you do that in lyx)

Comment: If that doesn't work, put them into a .tex file and use \include{mysdefs} or \input{mydefs}.  You can also use relative or absolute addressing: \input{../folder/mydefs}

Comment: @JohnKormylo -- `\input` is definitely preferable to `\include` for a file of macros, and `\usepackage` is the best of the lot.

Comment: I use MikTeX/TeXnic and have never gotten \usepackage to work on a file I created.  First of all, TeXnic will not allow you to create a STY file.  You have to copy an existing STY file, rename it and replace the contents.  More to the point, the STY files are all over the place.  There must be a directory somewhere that tells MikTex where to look, and it does NOT include the local folder.